# Pythonic way to generate random uniformly distributed points within hollow square lamina

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, random

Suppose we have a hollow square lamina of size n. That is, we have a nxn square from which a k*l rectangle has been removed (1<=k,l<=n-2). I want to calculate an average of distances between 2 random, uniformly distributed points within such hollow square lamina. 
For the sake of simplicity let's consider n=3, k=l=1, or a 3x3 square from whose center a unit square has been removed

I wrote this code for numpy, but it has at least 2 problems: I have to throw away approximately 1/9 of all generated points and removing the numpy.array elements requires lots of RAM:

```
    x,y = 3*np.random.random((2,size,2))
x = x[
    np.logical_not(np.logical_and(
        np.logical_and(x[:,0] > 1, x[:,0] < 2),
        np.logical_and(x[:,1] > 1, x[:,1] < 2)
        ))
    ]
y = y[
    np.logical_not(np.logical_and(
        np.logical_and(y[:,0] > 1, y[:,0] < 2),
        np.logical_and(y[:,1] > 1, y[:,1] < 2)
        ))
    ]
n = min(x.shape[0], y.shape[0])
```

UPD:Here `size` is the sample size of which I'm going to calculate average. 
Is there an elegant way to generate those points right away, without removing the unfit ones?

UPD: Here is the full code just for the reference:

```
def calc_avg_dist(size):
    x,y = 3*np.random.random((2,size,2))
    x = x[
        np.logical_not(np.logical_and(
        np.logical_and(x[:,0] > 1, x[:,0] < 2),
        np.logical_and(x[:,1] > 1, x[:,1] < 2)
        ))
    ]
    y = y[
        np.logical_not(np.logical_and(
        np.logical_and(y[:,0] > 1, y[:,0] < 2),
        np.logical_and(y[:,1] > 1, y[:,1] < 2)
        ))
    ]
    n = min(x.shape[0], y.shape[0])
    diffs = x[:n,:] - y[:n,:]
    return np.sum(np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->i',diffs,diffs)))/n
```

Comment: Why you don't write things like `1 < ... < 2`? AFAIK it works in Python.

Comment: @hyst329: `1 < x < 2` and its variants don't work with numpy arrays, because this is syntactically interpreted as `(1 < x) and (x < 2)`, and there's no way for numpy to override the `and` behaviour.

Comment: Upd: added a comment about what size is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the center removed, there are 8 regions that should contain points.  These are their lower-left corners:

```
In [350]: llcorners = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [0, 1], [2, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2]])
```

The regions are 1x1, so they have the same area and are equally likely to contain a given random point.  The following chooses `size` lower-left corners:

```
In [351]: corner_indices = np.random.choice(len(llcorners), size=size)
```

Now generate `size` (x,y) coordinates in the unit square:

```
In [352]: unit_coords = np.random.random(size=(size, 2))
```

Add those to the lower-left corners chosen previously:

```
In [353]: pts = unit_coords + llcorners[corner_indices]
```

`pts` has shape `(size, 2)`.  Here's a plot, with `size = 2000`:

```
In [363]: plot(pts[:,0], pts[:,1], 'o')
Out[363]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x11000f950>]
```

[image: plot]

---

*Update* to address the updated question...

The following function generalizes the above idea to a rectangular shape containing a rectangular hollow.  The rectangle is still considered to be nine regions, with the middle region being the hollow.  The probability of a random point being in a region is determined by the area of the region; `numpy.random.multinomial` is used to select the number of points in each region.

(I'm sure there is room for optimization of this code.)

```
from __future__ import division

import numpy as np


def sample_hollow_lamina(size, outer_width, outer_height, a, b, inner_width, inner_height):
    """
    (a, b) is the lower-left corner of the "hollow".
    """
    llcorners = np.array([[0, 0], [a, 0], [a+inner_width, 0],
                          [0, b], [a+inner_width, b],
                          [0, b+inner_height], [a, b+inner_height], [a+inner_width, b+inner_height]])
    top_height = outer_height - (b + inner_height)
    right_width = outer_width - (a + inner_width)
    widths = np.array([a, inner_width, right_width, a, right_width, a, inner_width, right_width])
    heights = np.array([b, b, b, inner_height, inner_height, top_height, top_height, top_height])
    areas = widths * heights
    shapes = np.column_stack((widths, heights))

    regions = np.random.multinomial(size, areas/areas.sum())
    indices = np.repeat(range(8), regions)
    unit_coords = np.random.random(size=(size, 2))
    pts = unit_coords * shapes[indices] + llcorners[indices]

    return pts
```

For example,

```
In [455]: pts = sample_hollow_lamina(2000, 5, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3)

In [456]: plot(pts[:,0], pts[:,1], 'o', alpha=0.75)
Out[456]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x116da0a50>]

In [457]: grid()
```

[image: plot]

Note that the arguments do not have to be integers:

```
In [465]: pts = sample_hollow_lamina(2000, 3, 3, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 0.5)

In [466]: plot(pts[:,0], pts[:,1], 'o', alpha=0.75)
Out[466]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x116e60390>]

In [467]: grid()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: This works great for the 3x3 square. But imagine running a loop through all admissible squares in a 40x40 square lamina. This will be extremely slow...

Comment: If you have a more general problem in mind, you should edit the question and explain the full problem.  As it is now, the question is specifically about the 3x3 case.

Comment: Wow! for some reason I didn't realize that no matter what the actual measurements are, there are still 8 rectangles! This simple fact escaped me :( Thanks so much for the code and even more so for the idea!!

Comment: Well, for some reason it didn't occur to me until just now that the same idea could be applied using just four rectangular regions; for example, everything below the hollow, everything above the hollow, and the two regions on either side of the hollow.  I'll leave that simplification as an exercise for the reader. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've already posted a shorter and somehow unclear answer,
here I've taken the time to produce what I think is a better answer.

---

Generalizing the OP problem, we have a "surface" composed of `nsc * nsr`
squares disposed in `nsc` columns and `nsr` rows, and a "hole" composed
of `nhc * nhr` squares (corresponding to the surface squares) disposed
in a rectangular arrangement with `nhr` rows and `nhc` columns, with
the origin placed at `ohc, ohr`

```
    +------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+ nsr  
    |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |  
    |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |  
 ...+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+ nsr-1  
    |      |      | oooo | oooo |      |      |      |      |      |  
    |      |      | oooo | oooo |      |      |      |      |      |  
    +------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+ ...  
    |      |      | oooo | oooo |      |      |      |      |      |  
    |      |      | oooo | oooo |      |      |      |      |      |  
    +------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+ ...  
    |      |      | oooo | oooo |      |      |      |      |      |  
    |      |      | oooo | oooo |      |      |      |      |      |  
 ohc+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+ 1  
    |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |  
    |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |  
    +------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+ 0  
    0      1      2     ...                         ...   nsc-1   nsc  
                  |             |  
                ohr=2        ohr+nhr
```

Our aim is to draw `n` random points from the surface without the hole
(the *admissible surface*) with a uniform distribution over the
admissible surface.

We observe that the admissible area is composed of 
`nsq = nsc*nsr -nhc*nhr` equal squares:
if we place a random point in an abstract unit square and then assign, with equal probability, that
point to one of the squares of the admissible area, we have done our
job.

In pseudocode, if `random()` samples from an uniformly distributed random variable over `[0, 1)`

```
(x, y) = (random(), random())
square = integer(random()*nsq)
(x, y) = (x, y) + (column_of_square_origin(square), row_of_square_origin(square))
```

To speed up the process, we are using `numpy` and we try to avoid, as far as possible,
explicit `for` loops.

With the names previously used, we need a listing of the origins of
the admissible squares, to implement the last line of the pseudo code.

```
def origins_of_OK_squares(nsc, nsr, ohc, ohr, nhc, nhr):

    # a set of tuples, each one the origin of a square, for ALL the squares
    s_all = {(x, y) for x in range(nsc) for y in range(nsr)}

    # a set of tuples with the origin of the hole squares
    s_hole = {(x, y) for x in range(ohc,ohc+nhc) for y in range(ohr,ohr+nhr)}

    # the set of the origins of admissible squares is the difference
    s_adm = s_all - s_hole

    # return an array with all the origins --- the order is not important!
    # np.array doesn't like  sets
    return np.array(list(s_adm))
```

We need to generate `n` random points in the unit square, organized in an array of shape `(n,2)`

```
    rand_points = np.random.random((n, 2))
```

We need an array of `n` admissible squares

```
    placements = np.random.randint(0, nsq, n)
```

We translate each point in `rand_points` in one of the admissible
squares, as specified by the elements of `placements`.

```
    rand_points += origins_of_OK_squares(nsc, nsr, ohc, ohr, nhc, nhr)[placements]
```

taking advantage of the extended addressing that it is possible for
`numpy` arrays, and its done...

In an overly compact function

```
import numpy as np
def samples_wo_hole(n,  nsc, nsr, ohc, ohr, nhc, nhr):
    s_all = {(x, y) for x in range(nsc) for y in range(nsr)}
    s_hole = {(x, y) for x in range(ohc,ohc+nhc) for y in range(ohr,ohr+nhr)}
    rand_points = np.random.random((n, 2))
    placements = np.random.randint(0, nsc*nsr - nhc*nhr, n)
    return rand_points+np.array(list(s_all-s_hole))[placements]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 8 equal unit squares in which it is admissible to place points, so draw as many points in an unit square as you want as in

```
x = np.random(n, 2)
```

now it suffices to choose at random in which of the 8 admissible squares each point is placed

```
sq = np.random.randomint(0, 8, n)
```

you need also an array of origins

```
delta = np.array([[0, 0],
                  [1, 0],
                  [2, 0],
                  [0, 1],
                  # no central square
                  [2, 1],
                  [0, 2],
                  [1, 2]
                  [2, 2]])
```

and finally

```
x = x + delta[sq]
```

---

To generalize the solution, write a function to compute an array of the origins of the admissible squares, a possible implementation using sets being

```
def origins(n, hole_xor, hole_wd, hole_yor, hole_hg):
    all_origins = {(x,y) for x in range(n) for y in range(n)}
    hole_origins = {(x,y) for x in range(hole_xor, hole_xor+hole_wd)
                          for y in range(hole_yor, hole_yor+hole_hg)}
    return np.array(list(all_origins-hole_origins)))
```

and use it like this

```
delta = origins(12,  4,5,  6,2)
n_squares = len(delta) # or n*n - width*height
target_square = np.random.randomint(0, n_squares, size)
x = x + delta[target_square]
```